# How can I use a "pre-defined Range" as my Pivot table data source

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have the following code

```
Dim S As Range

Set S = Range(Sheets(1).Cells(4, 2), Sheets(1).Cells(18, 9))

Sheets(4).PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=S, Version:=xlpivotversion14)
```

This gives me an "Invalid procedure or argument" error!

however when I use the range instead of "S" like the following:

```
Sheets(4).PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\[FY19_Proposed_Sheet_V2.xlsm]Proposed Projects!R5C1:R29C18" _
        , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
```

I get no errors!

I want to use "S" so that I can actively change and update it. the specified fixed range in the code is hypothetical.

Thanks,
Matt!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have to provide a string referencing the `Range` you wish to set as `SourceData`. The following will work:

```
Sub Test()
Dim S As Range

Dim shName as string
Dim rngAddress as string
Dim sourceDataStr as string 'Has to hold both sheetname and address.

Set S = Range(Sheets(1).Cells(4, 2), Sheets(1).Cells(18, 9))

shName = Sheets(1).Name 'Capture sheet name of where the range is in your case
rngAddress = S.Address 'Get the address for reference.
sourceDataStr = shName & "!" & rngAddress 'Get the correct sourceData string

Sheets(4).PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=sourceDataStr , Version:=xlpivotversion14) 'Tadaaaaa...
End Sub
```

Not the shortest possible / most optimezed code, but it's a sample after all.

Comment: Thanks Rik, But it didn't work! "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" is comes up ...

Comment: Try omitting the version parameter in the PivotCaches.Create method. That one is specific to your Excel version.

Comment: Nope! The error message changed to Run-Time error '-2147024809 (80070057)'

Comment: Is the referenced range valid for functioning as a pivot cache? E.g. continuous range with unique column headers? Also are you sure about the indices of the sheets?

Comment: Yes, I rechecked all those! I did one more test. I copied the whole Source out of the one with fixed value, which works properly: "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\[FY19_Proposed_Sheet_V2.xlsm]Proposed Projects!R5C1:R29C18" and put it into the variable you introduced "sourceDataStr " and used the variable in Sheets(4).PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=sourceDataStr , Version:=xlpivotversion14) .... It doesn't work! isn't it strange?

Comment: Yaay!! Found the root cause of error! Actually we need to use RngAddress = S.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) and it works ...

Comment: Only the root cause if your reference style is set like that for the workbook I think. Just passing the range as listed in answer works on my end. I'd have to test it with the different setting too.